# C- while loop un-explained behaviour

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, printf

I am trying to run the following code :

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned int ms, oldms = 0,dif;
struct timeval tv;
while(1)
{
 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 ms=tv.tv_sec; 
 //printf("%d\n",ms-oldms );
 dif=ms-oldms;
 if(dif>3)
   {    
        printf("3 seconds up");
        oldms=ms;
   }
 }
}
```

I am expecting it to print "3 seconds up" after every 3 seconds, but it doesn't display that message.
I tried to debug it using gdb but nothing seems wrong and still no output.
While trying to debug, I added a printf statement and magically the output can be seen.

If I run the program after removing the  //printf("%d\n",ms-oldms ); statement , there is no output again.I am not sure what's happening and whether its dependant on anything.

$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: Try putting a newline on your printf

Comment: @Jorgel , putting a newline in printf worked. But , I am still confused about this behaviour . This is the first time I encountered this.

Comment: You have infinite loop - that is the "first time". Even without newline it will work OK if you add `break` after `printf`.

Comment: `stdout` (to which `printf()` writes) is usually buffered and you usually won't see anything until you've printed a line-feed (or called `fflush(stdout)`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Output buffering is the reason.

`stdout` is line buffered by default when attached to a terminal device. You can flush this out using `fflush(stdout);` or using `\n` in `printf()` i.e. `printf("3 seconds up\n");`.
or disabling it with `setbuf(stdout, 0);`

I/O is slow in general. So implementations use a fixed size buffer and printf once it gets full.
In practice, calling `fflush(stdout);` too often can affect performance.

Comment: So this problem is with the printf right ? from your ans I assume there is nothing wrong with the while loop or large volume of processing happening in the code.

Comment: Yes. Nothing wrong with the loop.But I wouldn't say it is a "problem". There's a good reason why libc implementations do buffering: performance.

Comment: either printf("3 seconds up\n"); or printf("\n3 seconds up"); didn't work. Even adding a new printf("\n") just before the printf("3 seconds up\n") didnt help. The code works properly if i put a printf("\n") instead of the commented printf (//printf("%d\n",ms-oldms );)  in code

Comment: @kid The "volume of processing" is because of your infinite loop. There is no `sleep` in this loop and it is normal to get 100% CPU load.

Comment: @kid `\n` will work only if you printing on the console, not if you are doing some sort of redirection. For example, if you are doing `./a.out > file` then not. So call `fflush(stdout);` after the printf statement.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code has a couple of problems

1. the variable `oldms` is not being set to any specific value before the elapsed time is being checked
2. without either a call to `fflush(stdout);` or a trailing newline ('\n') in the format string, nothing will be output (for a very long time, until the system stdout buffer is filled)
3. for readability, the axiom `only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement` is applied to the code

the following code compiles cleanly and performs the desired operation

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int ms;
    unsigned int oldms = 0;
    unsigned int dif;
    struct timeval tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    oldms = tv.tv_sec;

    while(1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        ms=tv.tv_sec;
        //printf("%d\n",ms-oldms );
        dif=ms-oldms;

        if(dif>3)
        {
            printf("3 seconds up\n");
            oldms=ms;
        }
    }
} // end function: main
```